# NSPredicate searching for 1:N - 1:N entities

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have an Entity called AcademicYear that has a relationship 1:N with an entity called Subject which has a 1:N relationship with an Entity called SubjectLanguage:

**AcademicYear<--->>Subject<--->>SubjectLanguage**

I would like to filter the result of a query on AcademicYear in order to be able to gather Subject and SubjectLanguage already filtered by the parameter language.

On runtime i'll use such expression:
    academicYear.hasSubjects.hasLanguages.subjectName 
and i would like to be sure they are of a specific language filtered by the starting query.

i tried using during the fetch the following predicate (with no result):

```
NSPredicate *predicateLang = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL hasSubjects.hasLanguages.language like %@", language];
```

---

### NEW (Update)

Due to Marcus suggestion i changed the fetch request in this way:

```
NSError *error;
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * yearString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",year];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongToAcademicYear.yearId == %@ and ANY hasLanguages.language CONTAINS[cd] %@", yearString, language];



NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Subject"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
return [self arrayToMutableArrayConverter:fetchedObjects];
```

}

then i tested this solution with the following code:

```
NSArray * currentSubjects = [self.coordinator fetchSubjectThatBelongsToAcademicYear:1];
Subject * currentSubject = currentSubjects[0];
NSUInteger count = currentSubject.hasLanguages.count;
XCTAssertEqual(count, 1, @"riscontrati troppi languages. non è stato fatto il filtro su language");
```

I found the filter did not work correctly and i found two languages while i expect one. I'm pretty sure the issue is related with the predicate.

Any support is appreciated

kind regards

Nicolò

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse this a little bit.  Instead of fetching `AcademicYear` and then trying to reach over to `SubjectLanguage`, search for `Subject`.

Build your `NSFetchRequest` against `Subject` and change the predicate to:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"academicYear == %@ and ANY languages.language CONTAINS[cd] %@", academicYear, language];
```

Some comments:

- Your relationships should not start with "has".  They should just be `academicYear` and `languages`.  Singular for to-one and plural for to-many.
- Your entity `SubjectLanguage` should not have a property called `language`. Something that relates to the entity can be less descriptive.  `name` would work well so that it is the "`name` of the `SubjectLanguage`".

### Update

It worked exactly right.  You found the Subject that has the language and the year you are looking for.  It returned that Subject and *ALL* of its relationships.  Since there is more than one language associated with the subject it gave you access to all of the languages.

The predicate is correct, your test is flawed.  Your test should be insuring that one of the languages is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Dear Marcus i tried out your suggestion (except the one to change relation name since at this point of the project it will be a trouble). At the and of the modifications the code looks like written above (please see the NEW part). I would appreciate if you could provide some more suggestion.